# What would be a good pattern to display a photo gallery from the web on an iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview

I need to display a series of banner images from the web inside an iOS app. Pretty much like this:

[image]

I'll get the list of images to be displayed from an API call.

My struggles started when I started considering what should happen when the user rotate the phone. Given the constraints, the image will expand, keeping aspect ratio and leading and trailing distance of 15 from the superview.

Given that screen resolutions are very diverse, what should be width of the images saved on the server? Rotating the phone doesn't change screen scale, right?

But the available width changes. So, should I send the width available so the server can either generate or return the appropriate image? But then, I need to find a way to get notified when the screen rotates and reload the appropriate image, right?

Is that the right way to go? Or maybe webview would be the best option here (even though I'm gonna need to handle click events for those images)?

Comment: What is the size of your images? Providing images for sizes such as iPad Pro landscape could be very large. Consider changing the design of your app, perhaps using a split view controller, for example.

Comment: give images aspect ratio.. and let the images grow.. I think it should be 1 or 1 and half.